# Cannot read .json from a google cloud bucket

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage

I have a folder structure within a bucket of google cloud storage

```
bucket_name = 'logs'
json_location = '/logs/files/2018/file.json'
```

I try to read this `json` file in `jupyter notebook` using this code

```
from google.cloud import storage 

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "logs/files/2018/file.json"

def download_blob(source_blob_name, bucket_name, destination_file_name): 
    """Downloads a blob from the bucket.""" 
    storage_client = storage.Client() 
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name) 
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name) 

    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name) 

    print('Blob {} downloaded to {}.'.format(
        source_blob_name, 
        destination_file_name))
```

Then calling the function

```
download_blob('file.json', 'logs', 'file.json')
```

And I get this error

```
DefaultCredentialsError: File /logs/files/2018/file.json was not found.
```

I have looked at all the similar question asked on stackoverflow and cannot find a solution.

The `json` file is present and can be open or downloaded in the json_location on google cloud storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different perspectives regarding the json file you refer:

1) The json file used for authenticating to GCP.

2) The json you want to download from a bucket to your local machine.

For the first one, if you are accessing remotely to you Jupyter server, most probably the json doesn't exist in such remote machine, but in your local machine. If this is your scenario try to upload the json to the Jupyter server. Executing `ls -l /logs/files/2018/file.json` in the remote machine could help to verify its correctness. Then, `os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "JSON_PATH_ON_JUPYTER_SERVER"` should work.

On the other hand, I executed your code and got:

```
>>> download_blob('static/upload_files_CS.png', 'bucketrsantiago', 'file2.json')  
Blob static/upload_files_CS.png downloaded to file2.json.
```

The file gs://bucketrsantiago/static/upload_files_CS.png was downloaded to my local machine with the name file2.json. This helps to clarify that the only problem is regarding the authentication json file.

Answer (score 1):

`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is supposed to point to a file on the local disk where you are running jupyter.  You need the credentials in order to call GCS, so you can't fetch them from GCS.

In fact, you are best off not messing around with credentials at all in your program, and leaving the client library to it. Don't touch `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` in our application. Instead:

- If you are running on GCE, just make sure your GCE instances [has a service account with the right scopes and permissions]. Applications running in that instance will automatically have the permissions of that service account.
- If you are running locally, install [google cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) and run `gcloud auth application-default login`. Your program will then automatically use whichever account you log in as.

Complete instructions [here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/core/auth.html)